# What is a term for the hierarchical relationship between parent and child configuration options in software?

Tags: word-choice

Frequently we see configuration options with a hierarchical structure, often shown in a tree view. When enabling a parent option, all of the child options are enabled. When disabling the parent option, all of the child options are disabled. A user may be able to enable a subset of child options without "fully" enabling the parent option.

I am writing instructions/documentation and would like to explain this behavior in a simple, concise manner.

> "Enabling or disabling the parent option, by `__________`, enables or disables all child options as well."

I've thought of "by design," "by association;" but neither of these express my meaning as intended.

What would be an appropriate word to use here, or a proposed rewrite of the statement to accomplish my goal?

Comment: It sounds as though your intention is to indicate what happens in the normal case, when no special steps are taken to ensure that only a subset of the child options are affected by an action. In that case, I believe the standard phrase in that case would be "by default"—that is, by the ordinary operation of the program structure as designed.

Comment: Might "by proxy" work here?  The child options are not being disabled on their own, but through the acts (or actions upon) of another.

Comment: "by inheritance" ...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The nomenclature of a "parent" and a "child" implies that what affects the parent will influence the entirety of the children. Therefore, I would suggest eliminating any clarification.

> "Enabling or disabling the parent option enables or disables all child
>   options as well."

Comment: Succinct. This is a case where less is more; thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 6):

If your audience is technical users, most would consider this to be recursion.  If you're operating on a directory and all of its subdirectories, for example, you would use a "recursive" command line option:

> Enabling or disabling the parent option recursively enables or disables all child options as well

Comment: To be precise, it recursively enables/disables all _immediate_ children.  Usually, "children" informally includes grandchildren (and etc), making "recursively" redundant, yet at the same time, slightly more accurate...

Answer (score 2):

> Enabling or disabling the parent option, enables or disables all related child options as well.

Also the word *cascading* comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

I would use **recursively**,  although "cascading" does convey much of the meaning, that is used more often in user interfaces in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The correct technical term is "***composition***". Compare with "***aggregation***"

> ```
> A "owns" B = Composition : B has no meaning or purpose in the system without A
> A "uses" B = Aggregation : B exists independently (conceptually) from A
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you actually mean all children *and* grandchildren, etc. So I would use something like:

```
 "Any change to an option sets or resets all its sub-options too."
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***"Enabling or disabling the parent option, enables or
>   disables all child options as well, unless specifically overridden by the user"***

This slight modification makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say perhaps you mean options, and the switches or arguments that relate to them?  for instance you would run program X with the option /revert and the argument --all to the revert option?

Answer (score 0):

I like @mplungjan's suggestion of *cascading*, but would also suggest *indirectly*:

> Enabling or disabling the parent option ***indirectly*** enables or disables all related child options.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
   "Any change to the parent option, affects all its children"
```

And since you mentioned tree hierarchies, you could say something to the extent of:

```
   "All child nodes are enabled/disable based on the setting of the parent node."
```

(this might also imply that your tree acts as a filter as you travel down it)

In any case, I hope this helps.